# index from a list like find in string - python

Tags: python

I know i can find from a string with `str.find` and find from a list with `list.index` but here's my question:

```
'12345'.find('3') >>> [1,2,3,4,5].index(3)
'12345'.find('234') >>> [1,2,3,4,5].?
```

Edit:
I understand that there is no such a thing as what i asked but i need to write extra code for it.

thanks to all.

Comment: serarch in str and list work differently

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: Yes it can definitely help but i want a direct way.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean "a direct way"?

Comment: I don't understand your edit - *"but i need to write extra code for it."* Yes, you are correct, there is no built-in method for this, and you'll need to write a function to do it. So what?